# identify the inside range of two cell reference

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I want to create something like this.
There will be two cell. one for input one cell reference and another for another cell reference.
example : What is the range inside cell A1 and A10?
The answer is "A2:A9".
The good point is that my references will be always in same column.
Is there any way of doing it?

I tried

```
    =A10 - A1
```

But it's of no use.
I think loop is some kind of use but aren't able to find out.
Help!

Comment: "There will be two cell. one for input one cell reference and another for another cell reference" Explain it better. Reference compared to what?

Comment: suppose I want to show the inside range of a1 and a10.   If i put a1 in one cell and put a10 in another cell then the result will be "a2:a9". Am I clear enough brother?

Comment: What is the inside range of A1:B15?

Comment: It's critical. That's why my range will be always in same column. Like a1:a15 okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the formual:

```
=CONCATENATE("A",RIGHT(B1,LEN(B1)-1) +1,":A",RIGHT(C1,LEN(C1)-1) -1)
```

It extracts the cell numbers, then add/remove to have the inside range. Finally, it concatenates the results.

[image]

Comment: awesome bro. You are amazing. God bless you!

Comment: An icky note: This will break for columns beyond "Z"

Comment: @Hannu Correct.

Comment: @Hannu OP said the ranges will always be in the same column so it doesn't need to be dynamic it that sense

Comment: Yes. My experience though is that similar things comes back and "bite" you sooner or later ;-)

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio will you check out this problem? https://superuser.com/q/1580665/1207783

Answer (score 1):

If I amend your wording slightly, my interpretation ends up with this:

A2: `A1`
A3: `A10`
A4: `=CELL("address",OFFSET(INDIRECT(A2),0,1))`
A5: `=CELL("address",OFFSET(INDIRECT(A3),0,-1))`
A6: `=COLUMNS(INDIRECT(A4&":"&A5))`

A2 and A3; Left and right ends of a range.
A4 and A5: 1 cell "inside" the range ends.
A6: Number of cells in the inside-range.

Comment: LibreOffice 6.4.5.2, Build ID: 1:6.4.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 - seems to have rows and columns swapped in OFFSET() and ROWS()/COLUMNS().  *sigh*