# if function don't checks else if statement

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have a code that if my targeted cells value is nothing I mean empty then it will jump to the skip line. And if the targeted cells value is not empty then the code will run.

Here is the code :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim row As Integer
Dim copyRange As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pwd As String

    row = Range("$I$2").Value
    copyRange = "A" & row
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    

If Target.Cells = "$I$2" And Target.Value = "" Then
    GoTo Skip

ElseIf Target.Cells = "$I$2" And Target.Value <> "" Then
    Range(copyRange).EntireRow.Insert
    Range("M" & row & ":O" & row).Clear
    Range(copyRange & ":AA" & row).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
    Range(copyRange).Value = "General"
    Range(copyRange & ":I" & row).Merge
    Range(copyRange & ":I" & row).Locked = True
    Range(copyRange).EntireRow.Font.Bold = True
    Range(copyRange).EntireRow.Font.Size = 16
    Range(copyRange).EntireRow.Font.Name = "Arial"
    Range("J" & row).Value = "Type"
    Range("J" & row & ":L" & row).Merge
    Range("J" & row & ":L" & row).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    Range("J" & row & ":L" & row).IndentLevel = 1
    Range("J" & row & ":L" & row).Locked = True
    Range("M" & row & ":O" & row).Merge
    Range("M" & row & ":O" & row).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlThin
    Range("M" & row & ":O" & row).IndentLevel = 2
    Range("M" & row & ":O" & row).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="Belly 270,Tonello 420,Avantec 420,Acid Wash 270,Ozone 420"
    Range("P" & row).Value = "Qty"
    Range("P" & row & ":R" & row).Merge
    Range("P" & row & ":R" & row).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    Range("P" & row & ":R" & row).IndentLevel = 2
    Range("T" & row).Value = "pcs"
    Range("T" & row).Font.Size = 14
    Range("U" & row & ":AA" & row).Merge
End If

Skip:

MsgBox "End Of VBA!"

End Sub
```

But the problem is when my targeted cell is empty then it jumps to the skip line successfully but when the targeted cell is not empty then also it jumps to the skip line. It don't check my code inside the else if statement.
Help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this syntax:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I2")) Is Nothing Then
Select Case True
Case Target.Value = vbNullString
MsgBox "Empty"
Case Not IsNumeric(Target.Value)
MsgBox "Enter a number"
Case IsNumeric(Target.Value)
    Dim rw As Integer
    Dim copyRange As String
    Dim pwd As String
    rw = Range("$I$2").Value
    copyRange = "A" & rw
    Range(copyRange).EntireRow.Insert Range("M" & rw & ":O" & rw).Clear
    Range(copyRange & ":AA" & rw).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
    Range(copyRange).Value = "General"
    Range(copyRange & ":I" & rw).Merge
    Range(copyRange & ":I" & rw).Locked = True
    Range(copyRange).EntireRow.Font.Bold = True
    Range(copyRange).EntireRow.Font.Size = 16
    Range(copyRange).EntireRow.Font.Name = "Arial"
    Range("J" & rw).Value = "Type"
    Range("J" & rw & ":L" & rw).Merge
    Range("J" & rw & ":L" & rw).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    Range("J" & rw & ":L" & rw).IndentLevel = 1
    Range("J" & rw & ":L" & rw).Locked = True
    Range("M" & rw & ":O" & rw).Merge
    Range("M" & rw & ":O" & rw).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlThin
    Range("M" & rw & ":O" & rw).IndentLevel = 2
    Range("M" & rw & ":O" & rw).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="Belly 270,Tonello 420,Avantec 420,Acid Wash 270,Ozone 420"
    Range("P" & rw).Value = "Qty"
    Range("P" & rw & ":R" & rw).Merge
    Range("P" & rw & ":R" & rw).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    Range("P" & rw & ":R" & rw).IndentLevel = 2
    Range("T" & rw).Value = "pcs"
    Range("T" & rw).Font.Size = 14
    Range("U" & rw & ":AA" & rw).Merge
MsgBox "End Of VBA!"
End Select
End If

End Sub
```

I changed your row variable to rw, try and avoid using variable names that are already used by the language (eg sheet1.range("I2").Row )

Comment: just amazing bro. Looking for this since a time. Thanks for the help. and stay connected.